# How to deploy nextjs on xampp?

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, build, xampp

I have a problem with build and deploy NextJS App on xampp server. What i need? The application have to host locally. If we have another computer on the same internet then app can be load in another computer.

[image]

The host link should be the name of the computer. I tried to execute the statement with React but unfortunately it doesn't work and shows me the folder.

[image]

This case works on react. Unfortunately, I don't know how to rebuild it on Next
[https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/create-simple-reactjs-application-and-host-in-xampp-4dae8e466c50](https://stackoverflow.com)

Please help